# Manipulating excel file using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have huge requirement to manipulate the excel file using vba code.

Requirements:
Filter out users which 
1.are not active (meeans "No")
2.do have a Cluster name(means only blank rows to be remain unchanged rest all must be delete )
3. select in State
BLR,  MIA, NCE, MAD blanks
4. Select in city
Bangalore, Hounslow, Madrid, Miami, blanks
5. Search in email address 
for @ora.gmail.com 
and delete rows with ora. results
6. save remaining users in a separate sheet – add appropriate Cluster name associations in respective column

```
NCE       nce.iis
BLR           sin.iis
MAD           muc.iis
MIA               atl.iis
```

7.the result has to be displayed in another sheet in the same workbook. if you excute multiple times the result must auto refresh instead of showing empty rows in sheet.

Raw Data:

```
            A            B          C           D               E               F
          Name         City        State       email        activeconnect     clustername
    1.   Alois         Bangalore    BLR         al@gmail.com      Yes        
    2.   Olaf          Honslow      LON        ol@gmail.com       Yes        muc.iis  
    3.   sree          Akp          VSKP       al@ora.gmail.com   No        
    4.   Feher         Hungary                 f@gmail.com        Yes         EBUD
    5.   Hajniss                                                  No          EBUD
    6.   Maria         Italy         ITA        m@gmail.com       Yes       EItaly
    7.   Hari          Hungary                  H@gmail.com       Yes        EBUD
    8.  Ponna          Madrid        MAD        p@ora.gmail.com   Yes      muc.iis
    9. puv             Miami          MIA       PUV@gmail.com     yes  
    10. kiran          Paris         FRA       Ki@ora.gmail.com   yes
```

Can anyone give some sophisticated code because the code which i have written with IF statement.

Here is my code

```
    Sub test()
    Dim filterrange As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
ws2.Name = "abc"

ws1.Activate
Set filterrange = ws1.Cells(2, ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)  ' get columns e.g. name, state, etc.

filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array("GBR" _
        , "MAD", "NCE", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="Yes" ' activeconnect
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=" ' clustername
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*@sca.com*", Operator:=xlAnd ' e-mail
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
         "Madrid", "Sophia-antipolis"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

For Each cell In filterrange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

If Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "" Then
   Select Case Cells(cell.Row, 11).Value
      Case "NCE"
        Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "nceiptccm.net"
      Case "MAD"
        Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "muciptccm.net"
     End Select
End If
Next cell

filterrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ws2.Activate
ws2.Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub
```

The desired output should be:

```
      A            B          C           D               E               F
      Name         City        State       email        activeconnect     clustername
1.   Alois         Bangalore     BLR         al@gmail.com      Yes       sin.iis 
2.    puv         Miami          MIA       PUV@gmail.com     yes        alt.iis
```

Comment: why don't you use the macro-recorder and autofilter?

Comment: @psychicebola i dont know how to use that. could you please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Dim filterrange as Range, row as Range, cell as Range
Dim newWb as workbook
Set filterrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(yourSheet).Cells(2, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(yourSheet).cells(1, columns.count).end(xltoleft).column) ' get columns e.g. name, state, etc.

filterrange.autofilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("BLR" _
        , "MAD", "MIA", "NCE", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Yes" ' activeconnect
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=" ' clustername
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*@ora.gmail.com*", Operator:=xlAnd ' e-mail
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Bangalore", "Honslow", "Madrid", "Miami"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

For Each cell In filterrange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

If Cells(cell.row, 8) = "" Then
   Select Case Cells(cell.row, 5).Value
      Case "NCE"
        Cells(cell.row, 8) = "nce.iis"
      Case "BLR"
        Cells(cell.row, 8) = "sin.iis"
      Case "MAD"
        Cells(cell.row, 8) = "muc.iis"
      Case "MIA"
        Cells(cell.row, 8) = "atl.iis"
   End Select
End If

Next cell
filterrange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Set newWb = Workbooks.Add

newWb.Sheets(1).Paste
```

If you need more information check this out: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx

Comment: it works perfectly for my requirement but the thing is the last requirement is not yet fullfilled. In the cluster name column it has to be filled with `nce.net` or `muc.net` these two are depend on the column state. if it is `nce.net` then the empty rows in cluster name column has to be filled with the corresponding name.

Comment: @pscychicebola its not working , i think its because of row number , im not sure.  i have like 15000 rows and its showing row number instead of 1,2,3......so on. beacuse of this the loop code is not working.

Comment: now its perfectly working. from my bottom of the heart i really appreciate you. thanks

Comment: i have a question. How ot use the macro automatically. I mean i have a raw data say 15k rows and 26 columns. When i excute that macro it should display the output . could you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: how do you mean automatically?

Comment: could you please tell me how to record the macro and resue the same macro multiple times.

Comment: i still don't get the purpose of this. if you have one file with a single range. it doesn't matter if you have 10 rows or 15k. executing the macro gives you the expected result.

Comment: is there any way that the result should be display in the another sheet (say sheet 2) but the raw data would remain unchange in same sheet (say sheet1). After that if you excute mulitple times in the sheet2 the result should be refresh again. it means it must delete the result in sheet2 and again has to be display in sheet 2. ? could you please let me know

Comment: If you want another sheet change the last two lines of code to `Thisworkbook.sheets(2).Paste` and the data in sheet 1 is not deleted at all. Read the Excel documentation to `AutoFilter` and if something on sheet 2 is missing, this is another problem but not the one you mentioned in the first place...

Comment: but when im using `thisworkbook.sheets(2).paste` its throwing an error. and one more thing is when I excuted the entire code its showing the result with only headers. Do you have any idea why its behaving like that?  Yesterday its works fine i dont know why today.

Comment: if it shows the headers only, no condition is met. do you have a second sheet in that workbook?

Comment: so what should i do have to put in my code. could you pls tell me.

Comment: you want to have the result in a second sheet rather than another workboobk?

Comment: Yes. another one is if you excute the code multiple times its automatically refresh the result in sheet2. I hope you understood what i mean?

Comment: then you better edit your question, otherwise my answer wouldn't make any sense and add a second worksheet to your workbook

Comment: After the `for loop` statement i used the below code `Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

Ws.Name = "sheet2"
filterrange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("sheet2").Paste` but it shown the result in the same sheet1 and creates a empty sheet2. I tried again now the magic is , in the first sheet it shown only header and creates a sheet3. could you pls help me out.

Comment: could please make a new question out of is? as fact that it's another problem which has to be solved.

Comment: I posted a new question. could you please check with that. My requirement is , the ouput should display in a new sheet(i.e sheet2)  but the actual data remains unchanged in sheet1. Instead when I am excuting, the expected result is showing in both sheet1 and sheet2 rather showing in sheet only , and creating a multiple sheets. could you pls help me out. see my edited code.

Comment: you should make a NEW question and not edit this one. therefore, my answer is not correct anymore and other users who have a similiar problem can't deal with it

Comment: FYI. I already posted a new question and as well as edited this question.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, could you please provide the link to the new question here?

Comment: Here is the link     [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355030/how-to-display-result-in-another-sheet-rather-showing-in-the-same-sheet-in-excel/32362352#32362352]

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another approach. I didn't have the time to test it here, so you might need to tweak it a bit. But I guess you get the idea.

```
Sub test()
Dim deleted_rows As Long
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim row_number As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Filter
For row_number = 2 To lastRow
    While row_number + deleted_rows <= lastRow And _
    (Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & row_number).Value2 = "No" Or _
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("F" & row_number).Value2 = vbNullString Or _
        (Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number).Value2 <> "MIA" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number).Value2 <> "MAD" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number).Value2 <> "NCE" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number).Value2 <> "BLR" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number).Value2 <> vbNullString) Or _
        (Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & row_number).Value2 <> "Bangalore" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & row_number).Value2 <> "Hounslow" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & row_number).Value2 <> "Madrid" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & row_number).Value2 <> "Miami" And _
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & row_number).Value2 <> vbNullString) Or _
        InStr(1, Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & row_number).Value2, "@ora.") > 0)
            Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(row_number).Delete
            deleted_rows = deleted_rows + 1
    Wend
    If row_number + deleted_rows >= lastRow Then Exit For
Next row_number

'Copy
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
    .Title = "Yes"
    .SaveAs Filename:="Yes.xlsx"
End With

Workbooks("Yes.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J" & lastRow - deleted_rows).Formula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:J" & lastRow - deleted_rows).Formula

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts  but unfortunately the code which you mentioned is not working anymore its deleting all rows.

Comment: im extremely sorry sheet1 and "WX Messenger Export 20150819" are same sheet. i must have to rename to Sheet1.

Comment: As I said, I simply didn't have the time to verify the entire code. But now I checked the conditions and (here) they deliver the requested result.

Comment: for me its throwing an error as "subscript out of range". could you please explain the role of `row_number + deleted rows`

Comment: This is just to make sure you're not running into an endless loop. For example: if the last row is 140 and in the meantime 5 rows got deleted then the code should only check up to row 135 because any row after that row needs to get deleted (because column F will be empty). That would result in the code running forever.

Comment: for me its throwing an as "subscript out of range"